# Как правильно работать с экземпляром класса на двух страницах? C#/UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Есть две страницы, на первой я создаю экземпляр класса, в который я добавляю данные. Перехожу на вторую страницу и они отображаются. Но когда я заново захожу на первую страницу, и создаю новые данные, они перезаписывают уже имеющиеся, а не добавляются. Я так понимаю, должен быть один экземпляр класса, в который я каждый раз буду добавлять данные, но как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я нашел решение, воспользовавшись передачей объекта класса как параметра во время перехода на другую страницу.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page), DS);
```

Где DS это то, что мы хотим передать, а Page та страница на которую переходим.